# Withings API subscription always returns 293

Tags: withings

I'm trying to set up a subscription on the Withings API.  (all other calls to the API are authenticated and produce valid returns).  The subscription always returns "293 - the callback URL is either absent or incorrect.  I've searched existing questions and everything seems to check out; tried http and https, my URL exists and testing in Postman shows it returns 200 - Ok and responds in 263 ms.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Removed the urlencode (sent an un-urlencoded URL) and the subscription worked.  Not sure why.